# Why is this true ? $(1-s)\zeta(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+1-s/2) A_k}{\Gamma(1-s/2) k!}$

Tags: calculus, riemann-zeta

On the whole complex plane the following formula is valid :

$$(1-s)\zeta(s) =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+1-s/2) A_k}{\Gamma(1-s/2) k!}$$

where $A_k = \sum_{j=0}^k (2j-1) \zeta(2j+2) (k,j)$

and $(k,j)$ is the binomial coefficient.

How to show this ?

Comment: OK for $k=2$, with some fiddling involving $\Gamma(0)$.  Seemed to fail for $s=3$ (series divergent).  Seemed to fail for $s=-1$ (series divergent).

Comment: Even with $(-1)^j$ and $2j+1$, I think the series diverges for $s=1$ and $s=3$.

Comment: @GEdgar Why should be the series divergent at $s=1,3$?

Comment: My error.  Numerically adding 100 terms gave me a big number; but using 50-decimal calculations it seems OK.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini because I forgot the (-1)^j term it might diverge ?? Just guessing.
Seems Edgar thinks not , but Im not sure if that is with or without the -1 term.

Comment: @mick With $(-1)^j$ is NOT a divergent series. This is a particular form of the functional equations of the Riemann Zeta function, that holds in all $\mathbb{C}$. And it's consistent to the fact that $(1-s)\zeta(s)$ is an entire function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that you lost $(-1)^{j}$ in $A_{k}.$ And my proof works with $(2j+1)$, so I think there is some problems. However, note that $$A_{k}=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left(-1\right)^{j}\dbinom{j}{k}\left(2j+1\right)\zeta\left(2j+2\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left(-1\right)^{j}\dbinom{j}{k}\left(2j+1\right)\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{2j+2}}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left(-1\right)^{j}\dbinom{j}{k}\left(2j+1\right)\frac{1}{n^{2j}}.$$
 Now rewrite the last term as $$\left(2j+1\right)\frac{1}{n^{2j}}=n\lim_{a\rightarrow1}\frac{d}{da}\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)^{2j+1}$$
 hence $$A_{k}=\lim_{a\rightarrow1}\frac{d}{da}\left(a\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left(-1\right)^{j}\dbinom{j}{k}\left(2j+1\right)\left(\frac{a^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)^{j}\right)$$ and the now we have a Newton expansion. So$$A_{k}=\lim_{a\rightarrow1}\frac{d}{da}\left(a\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left(1-\frac{a^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)^{k}\right).$$
 Using $$\sum_{k \geq 0}\frac{\Gamma\left(k+b\right)}{\Gamma\left(b\right)}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}=\left(1-x\right)^{b}$$
 we have $$\frac{1}{s-1}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{\Gamma\left(k+1-s/2\right)}{\Gamma\left(1-s/2\right)}\frac{A_{k}}{k!}=\frac{1}{s-1}\lim_{a\rightarrow1}\frac{d}{da}\left(a\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\Gamma\left(k+1-s/2\right)}{\Gamma\left(1-s/2\right)}\frac{\left(1-\frac{a^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)^{k}}{k!}\right)=\frac{1}{s-1}\lim_{a\rightarrow1}\frac{d}{da}\left(a^{1+s-2}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{\frac{s}{2}-1}\right)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{s}}=\zeta\left(s\right).$$

Comment: At first sight this seems correct.
A bit short perhaps.
I wonder if there are other ways to show it.
I accept for now and will read more carefully later.
Thank you +1

Comment: @mick What do you intend with a bit short? If you want I can expand it a little more.

Comment: For example, put in conditions for convergence of the series, like $|a|<n$ and $s > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**partial answer**
Corrected formula
$$
(s-1)\zeta(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+1-s/2) A_k}{\Gamma(1-s/2)k!}
\\
\text{where}\quad A_k = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j (2j+1)\zeta(2j+2)\binom{k}{j}
$$
For $s$ an even positive integer, avoid $\Gamma$-function poles by writing
$$
\frac{\Gamma(k+1-s/2)}{\Gamma(1-s/2)} = (1-s/2)(2-s/2)\cdots(k-s/2)
$$
Then the series is finite, and the identity is true for *any* function, not only $\zeta$.

That is, for any function $Z$, and any even positive integer $s$,
$$
(s-1)Z(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+1-s/2) A_k}{\Gamma(1-s/2)k!}
\\
\text{where}\quad A_k = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j (2j+1)Z(2j+2)\binom{k}{j}
$$

Comment: I assume the easiest proof of that is by induction.
I also assume you add the $(-1)^j$ that was missing in the OP as mentioned by Marco Cantarini.
And I also assume your prove is analogue to Marco's.
Thank you +1.